# Form submission return me to index.php

Tags: php, html

I always have this error when changing any form in my site from post to get and click on submit button redirecting me to `index.php`.

```
<form action="index.php?pg=users" method="get"> 
  <input type='text' placeholder='user name' name='guildn' id='guild'> 
  <input type='submit ' name='submit ' value='Search'>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of your form?

Comment: @MohamedHasan Where do you want to redirect it?

Comment: @MaihanNijat to this page ?pg=users but it's always redirect me to index.php?guildn=name&submit=Search and it should be index.php?pg=users&guildn=name&submit=Search

Comment: @MohamedHasan, Can you add your form sample in the question instead of showing it in comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to update your form a little,

For POST, doing this is fine :

```
<form action="index.php?pg=users" method="post">
    <input type='text' placeholder='user name' name='guildn' id='guild'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search'>
</form>
```

But for GET, in your form action you have **"index.php?pg=users"** where **"pg=users"** is part of your URL query string already.

You can move the **"pg=users"** as part your form **input with type hidden** like the example below :

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
    <input type='hidden' name='pg' value='users'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='user name' name='guildn' id='guild'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search'>
</form>
```

Remember that in method="GET", your input will be appended to your action URL on form submit and will ignore the query string in action URL.